# Changing the color of a cell after entering a different value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to automate the color changing that should happen after entering a different value in the next bottom cell.

The color should not change if the entered value is the same as the value entered in the cell above it.

The end result should look like this:

[image]

Comment: This sounds like conditional formatting.

Comment: Probably. I don't know how to use it in this specific situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, try this, selected the cells, but made sure that the cell A2 is allowed to move down ie not $A$2 but $A2:

[image]